# OMLinkedListImplFactory ClassCastException in Axis2

Tags: apache-axis

I am using Axis2 for connecting the SOAP web service. While connecting I am getting the following exception.

I am using the following jars :

**axis2 - 1.6.2**

**axiom-api - 1.2.14**

**axis2-transport-http - 1.6.2**

**Exception :**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.factory.OMLinkedListImplFactory cannot be cast to org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.OMFactoryEx
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXBuilder.<init>(StAXBuilder.java:129)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.<init>(StAXOMBuilder.java:106)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.factory.AbstractOMMetaFactory.internalCreateStAXOMBuilder(AbstractOMMetaFactory.java:81)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.factory.AbstractOMMetaFactory.createOMBuilder(AbstractOMMetaFactory.java:95)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.OMXMLBuilderFactory.createOMBuilder(OMXMLBuilderFactory.java:154)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.OMXMLBuilderFactory.createOMBuilder(OMXMLBuilderFactory.java:134)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.OMXMLBuilderFactory.createOMBuilder(OMXMLBuilderFactory.java:105)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.XMLUtils.toOM(XMLUtils.java:590)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.XMLUtils.toOM(XMLUtils.java:575)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DescriptionBuilder.buildOM(DescriptionBuilder.java:97)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.populateConfig(AxisConfigBuilder.java:90)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.populateAxisConfiguration(DeploymentEngine.java:857)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.FileSystemConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(FileSystemConfigurator.java:116)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:210)
    at com.emc.exsearchwebservice.driver.ExSearchWebServiceDriver.main(ExSearchWebServiceDriver.java:44)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I got the solution. Problem is mismatched jar version. Axis2 uses axiom-impl.1.2.13.jar, but I have included axiom-api.1.2.14.jar as dependency. Finally I changed the axiom-api version to 1.2.13, this solves the problem.